# Can I run another Command Prompt/GUI process in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I am writing a windows service that occasionaly has to renew IP address of the system and It would call ipconfig /renew to do it.
The code is going to look like this

```
            Process ipconfigProcess = new Process();                
            ipconfigProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig";
            ipconfigProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " /renew";
            ipconfigProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            ipconfigProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            ipconfigProcess.Start();
            strOutput = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            ipconfigProcess.WaitForExit();
```

I suppose a windows service is not allowed to show windows/dialogs. So my question is whether renewing ip as above would be a problem in windows service because it may or may not show a console to run ipconfig ?

Comment: Did you fix the problem? If not i have the solution for it.

Comment: @StevenHernandez: there isn't a problem to fix; `ipconfig /renew` should work perfectly in a service context.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Ive tested it before and a service cant call gui process or console apps like cmd.exe it does get created the process but it ignores the arguments and doesnt do anything at all.

Comment: @StevenHernandez: I've never had any trouble calling `cmd.exe` from a service.  I use one such service frequently.  I'm not sure what your problem is, but that's not it.

Comment: @Ahmed: are you able to confirm whether your code worked as posted or not?

Comment: @HarryJohnston If I remember correctly it did work without any issue, I will double check the code again and confirm it ..

Comment: @StevenHernandez: were you ever able to figure out what was wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only issue you're going to face is that of permissions - you should have no problem running a process like this (as long as you don't want to interact with any kind of UI), but your windows service needs to run as an account that will be able to spawn a process and execute ipconfig.

Comment: How could this be done? Like how could you make the windows service work as an account? Like I need it to be able to work with no user, because I won't have admin user name and pass all of the time.

Comment: All windows services have accounts that they run as, so you can specify an account like "admin" or you can use one of the built in accounts, for example "network service".

Comment: indeed. yeah I study more the matter, and was able to figure out a work around but had to ur Kernel32.dll to be able to trick the OS. And its working like a charm now. And it works for any UI or Console app not only cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

This does not require an instance of cmd.exe. Many command line applications are used in this manner.

Comment: That doesn't mean that it won't create a console.  If you launch a command-line executable directly, without cmd.exe, it still gets a console by default.

Answer (score -1):

A service can use GUI functions and/or create a console.  Windows creates a dummy display surface to draw on as necessary.  (Obviously, this dummy surface can't interact with the user.)

Comment: A Windows Service cant use GUI functions since windows Vista +... And before vista it required a setting of giving the windows service a special permission of user interaction by the service. This is all because of the Session 0 Microsoft created on the OS.

Comment: @StevenHernandez: actually, a Windows service *can* use GUI functions, even in Vista and later.  As stated in my answer, Windows creates a dummy display surface.  The GUI will not be displayed and cannot interact with the user, but from the executable's point of view everything will work normally, just as if you were running in a normal context with no user present.

Comment: Have you actually code this before?  Because I would love to see it working like that interacting with GUI Applications.

Comment: "I think stopping the service and continuing it its not very neat as a solution." ... what solution?  I'm not trying to solve a problem, I'm demonstrating that the problem you're talking about doesn't exist.

Comment: How come is not existant to you? If you want a service that can do GuI interactions or console interactions and its not possible because of the windows service limitation how is that not a problem?

Comment: @StevenHernandez: if you want your service to interact with the user, then there's a (solvable) problem.  That is not, however, what the OP was asking.